# Mod Rewrite to rewrite *.html files (CodeIgniter)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I'm sure this is probably really simple, but my knowledge really isn't good in this area, and I don't seem to be able to get it right.

I have the following file structure:

```
/cms (renamed from system)
cms.php (renamed from index.php, added to DirectoryIndex in .htaccess)
.htaccess
index.html
page1.html
/css
/js
```

I also have the .htaccess from the CI wiki. The part I think needs adjusting is:

```
#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to cms.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms.php?/$1 [L]
```

I want most files that already exist to be accessible, e.g. and .js, .css, .png, .swf etc, but any .htm or .html to be processed by cms.php.

For example, if the user requests http://localhost/index.html, index.html gets passed to cms.php, or if http://localhost/dir/page.html is requested, dir/page.html is passed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what wasn't working right with what you have?

Comment: Well it worked, but I was trying to catch the html files to process them before output. Eg, user requests index.html, "index.html" gets passed to the codeigniter application which loads the file, makes whatever changes, then echos out the contents. Needed it to work this way to keep it simple - designers only need to dump 3 files (/cms, cms.php and .htaccess) in their code to cms-ify it.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. (I knew there were issues with the original answer to this question, but didn't want to post an answer until I was sure what you wanted, looks like you got it figured out though, so glad to hear it's working!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a tutorial, and came up with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ cms.php?/$1 [NC]
```

So anything requested ending in .html is passed to cms.php, resulting in a URL like cms.php/index.html, which cms.php can process and output.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(*\.js|*\.png|*\.css|*\.swf|folder1|folder2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 
RewriteRule ^.\.htm cms\.php
RewriteRule ^.\.html cms\.php
</IfModule>
```

you can add other extensions and/or folders that you do not want re-directed to the `RewriteCond` line.

Comment: Ah, ok. Is there a way to reverse it, so I specify which files should be rewritten (.htm, .html)?

Comment: Yes. You can add additional `RewriteRule` lines to the file. I edited the answer with 2 examples of additional rewrite rules that will redirect `.htm` and `.html` files to `cms.php`.

Comment: Hmm, couldn't get it to work properly. However, I think I've sorted it - found a tutorial on it, and came up with RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)$ cms.php?/$1 [NC] which seems to do the job. Thanks anyway!